# How to first disassociate and then associate specific VLANs in Network Gateway vsrx

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am disassociating a specific VLAN [VLAN ID 2634795 which is route around] from the Network Gateway vsrx using API

func (r Network_Gateway_Vlan) DeleteObjects(templateObjects []datatypes.Network_Gateway_Vlan) (resp bool, err error)

then immediately I am associating multiple VLANs which also include [VLAN ID 2634795 route through]to the Network Gateway vsrx using API

func (r Network_Gateway_Vlan) CreateObjects(templateObjects []datatypes.Network_Gateway_Vlan) (resp []datatypes.Network_Gateway_Vlan, err error)

Sometimes I am getting error

Unable to create association:\n - \nSoftLayer_Exception_Public: VLAN ID 2634795 is an inside VLAN for gateway

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following rest call examples:

**Disassociate Vlan:**

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan/deleteObjects
```

Body: Json

```
{"parameters": [
    [
        {
            "id":11111
        }
    ]
]}
```

Change the "11111" data for your in insideVlan id.

To get the gateway insideVlans you can use the below rest call:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/[networkGatewayId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[insideVlans[networkVlan]]
```

Output:

```
{
    "accountId": 302354,
    "id": 25465,
    "insideVlans": [
        {
            "id": 11111,
            "networkGatewayId": 3321548,
            "networkVlanId": 412451,
            "networkGateway": {
                "accountId": 302354,
                "id": 24587
             }
         } ]
    }
```

**Associate Vlan**

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan/createObject
```

Body: Json

```
{"parameters":[

    {
        "bypassFlag":true,
        "networkGatewayId":22222,
        "networkVlanId":33333
    }

 ]

}
```

Change the "22222" and "33333" data for your networkGatewayId and networkVlanId.

To get the possible inside vlans(networkVlanId) to associate to a gateway you can use the following rest api call:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/[networkGatewayId]/getPossibleInsideVlans?objectMask=mask[networkSpace]
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "accountId": 31214,
        "id": 33333,
        "modifyDate": "2018-09-28T21:32:16+08:00",
        "name": "test-ams01",
        "primarySubnetId": 54547,
        "vlanNumber": 1454,
        "networkSpace": "PUBLIC"
    }
]
```

Comment: I am using the suggested API only , but problem is even though I have disassociated the specific VLAN using the deleteObjects API , after which I am trying to associate the same VLAN this time route through , then getting error that this is already a inside vlan.  Even tough after a short duration I can see VLAN is disassociated.   It appears to me  as timing issue , sometimes  vlan is associated sometimes not.

Comment: Try using the associate vlan body request without brackets, that's how the portal control works. I updated my answer.

Comment: I have to use the createObjects API so that I can associate multiple VLANS.

Comment: Sharing the link [https://sldn.softlayer.com/go/associate_vlan.go/] for the associate part  I am populating the template object for multiple vlan association and then invoking the createObjects API, I didnot get the how portal control works.

Comment: The control portal associates the vlans to a gateway one by one, that's why it uses https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan/createObject/, otherwise you can associate vlans using https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan/createObjects/. I tried both options and they are working for me.

Comment: F.Ojeda thanks for reply , for me also createObjects is working well, but issue I am facing when calling deleteObjects and then again calling createObjects. So sometime error I am getting related to inside VLAN while calling CreateObjects , it is complaining because one VLAN is common in deleteObjects and CreateObjects. Even though deleteObjects is invoked and finally VLAN is dis associated but it is not deleted immediately that is the reason createObjects is failing.

Comment: F.Ojeda by default the private backend VLAN is route around when we order vsrx gateway, is there way it can come as route through. Once the gateway is active I am deleting the associated VLAN and the associating a new list of VLAN which also include the private backend VLAN. Then I am seeing the issue that is inconsistent.

Comment: I tried again the requests  associate and disassociate multiple vlans and I did not get any error. You have to keep in mine that the possible vlans ids to associate to the gateway do not change, but if you see using this request: https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/[networkGatewayId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[insideVlans[networkVlan]] you will find that the insideVlans ids change and those ids you use to disassociate the vlans.

Comment: No problem with the private backend vlan added by default, you can disassociate and associate this vlan too. To get all the possible vlans to associate to the gateway use this request: https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/[networkGatewayId]/getPossibleInsideVlans?objectMask=mask[networkSpace]. All these requests are in my answer above.